# How to prevent the event change if use checkbox prop change?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a list of types that use  and a checkbox 
When select change the value, I make an AJAX call to load the value status and change the check box

```
$('input[name=status]').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Do ajax call update
        success: function (data) {
            // show alert
        }
    })
});
```

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Do ajax call load value
        success: function (data) {
            // load the data current status to the checkbox
            // $('input[name=status]').attr('checked', data.checked); This not work after click checkbox for change
            $('input[name=status]').prop('checked', data.checked); // This call event onChange and show the alert
        }
    })
});
```

The problem is

- When I use attr for update checkbox value after change select, if I check the checkbox for update the status of the current select type. The checkbox can't change if I change the select anymore.
- I use prop replace attr it work now but new problem is it will call the checkbox change event, this make the alert show every change the select value.

How to prevent the event change if use checkbox prop change?

Comment: Changing a property via Javascript does *not* fire an event (in general).  Perhaps you have some other code that is firing the event, eg `$("input[name=status]").change()`.  Here's your code, as provided, without the event firing when you change the `select`: https://jsfiddle.net/o5L6k9pv/  Please [edit] your question and add relevant HTML, enough to *demonstrate the issue within the question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no action like that. 
Maybe you can set a flag for this like adding a class, if have this class stop the change. 
Example:

```
$('input[name=status]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disable-ajax')) { // The ajax action can't be call if this has this class
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({});
});
$('select').on('change', function() {
    let inputElem = $('input[name=status]');
    $.ajax({
        success: function (data) {
            inputElem.addClass('disable-ajax'); // Add class for prevent the ajax in input onchange event
            inputElem.prop('checked', data.checked);
        }
    });
    inputElem.removeClass('disable-ajax');
});
```